# Anko Generate EditText and Give Them onClickListener to Move to Another EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I want to build a crossword game using Anko(Android Kotlin), It will generate the EditText and give them onCLickListener to Move(Vertically/Horizontally) to another EditText. I successfully generated the EditText but have no idea how to give them onClickListener to move to another EditText.

This is what I've done

```
class CrosswordActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        CrosswordActivityUI().setContentView(this)
    }
}

class CrosswordActivityUI : AnkoComponent<CrosswordActivity> {
    private val crossword = arrayOf(
            arrayOf("w", "o", "r", "k"),
            arrayOf("o", "", "u", ""),
            arrayOf("r", "u", "n", ""),
            arrayOf("k", "", "", "")
    )

    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<CrosswordActivity>) = ui.apply {
        verticalLayout {
            for (rows in crossword) {
                linearLayout {
                    for (column in rows) {
                        editText {
                            visibility = if (column.isNotEmpty()) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
                            onClick {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.view
}
```

I've built the game using React Native, just trying to rewrite it to Native Android. I'm a newbie in Native Android Development, let me know if there are another ways to do this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably not good to build the navigation logic into the Views this much ... but if you want to go this route: If you can extend your loops to have the index, then the onClick for each edit text can use these indexs to decide which EditText to focus next.

```
for ((index, value) in array.withIndex()) {
    println("the element at $index is $value")
}
```

You will also have to build a data structure to record the EditText for each cell, or perhaps use a GridLayout. This is so the onClick code for each EditText is able to look up its neighbors.

So you have psuedocode like:

```
onClick {
   val nextX = f(x)
   val nextY = g(y)
   editTextGrid[nextX][nextY].requestFocus()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've got an idea with GridLayout.